# Nav Bar with Div

Tags: html, css, navigation, nav

I want to make a Nav Bar with Divs, but I don't know how to put the links side by side. Would anybody be willing to help and/or explain to me? Adding filler words because it wont let me post. Lorem Ipsum ad usu quem delectus, sea stet sale id. Nulla nostrud appetere ea sed. Ne nam accumsan verterem, ex mea cetero voluptaria. In vel latine labores splendide. Justo atomorum est cu, bonorum maiestatis ea sit. His an nobis tractatos, sea ut possit vidisse, quodsi quaestio vim ne. An eum liber persecuti, duo patrioque consetetur ad, duo et sonet populo.

Eligendi appellantur voluptatibus has ea, eam eu putent constituto efficiantur. Vidit accusam liberavisse ad eum. Ne vel dicit soluta, exerci aliquam principes ius ea. Ius ut illum aeterno, ius officiis corrumpit ne, ut ancillae patrioque ius. Sea et maiorum apeirian, tritani concludaturque eam ad.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>My website</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../Web Design 3/stylesheet.css" />
</head>

<body>
    <div class="headbar">
        <div class="navigation">
            <div class="Home"><a href="#">Home</a></div>
            <div class="About"><a href="#">About</a></div>
            <div class="Products"><a href="#">Products</a></div>
            <div class="Contact"><a href="#">Contact</a></div>
        </div>
        <div class="logo">

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
@charset "UTF-8";
/* Stylesheet */

* {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

.headbar {
    width: 100%;
    height: 75px;
    background: black;
    opacity: 0.5;
}

.navigation {
    float:right;
    height: 50px;
    width: 500px;
    top: 6.5px;
}

.Home {
    height: 50px;
}
```

Comment: so you want a nav bar with link in one row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this

```
.navigation div
{
    display:inline;
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/peb55sza/

Answer (score 0):

If you want a simple nav bar then use this code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>My website</title>
<style>
    @charset "UTF-8";
/* Stylesheet */

* {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

.headbar {
    width: 100%;
    height: 75px;
    background: black;
    opacity: 0.5;
}

.navigation {
    float:right;
    height: 75px;
    line-height:75px;
    width: 500px;
}

.navigation div { float:left;display:block; width:15%;height:50px;}
.navigation div a {color:#fff;display:block;}
</style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="headbar">
        <div class="navigation">
            <div class="Home"><a href="#">Home</a></div>
            <div class="About"><a href="#">About</a></div>
            <div class="Products"><a href="#">Products</a></div>
            <div class="Contact"><a href="#">Contact</a></div>
        </div>
        <div class="logo">

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

i just updated your code..copy and paste and it will work..let me know if you have more question..be in mind, its just basic structure..hope i could help.

Comment: Thank you :) both of your comments woked